# Serve a file in a browser from a runtime directory using nodejs

Tags: node.js

In our application we store our reports in a user defined folders. User can add their own folders during runtime. Iam showing the history of those files in a web page. on clicking the file name i should show the file from the folder. How can i show the files from a non public directory.Since its given during runtime i havent added them as static dir to the express server.

One idea we tried was to use node-static-server and create a file server with the folder and serve the file. for each file we create this. it works fine but i get an error saying "port already in use". is there any better idea to do this? is this the right approach?

Comment: What you want to do is to serve a file in a directory and allow users to create the files in the directory after server has started, or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html ?

Comment: we allow users to configure folders after server has started. now how to serve those files? can i dynamically add the folders as static?

Comment: Every request will cause a file scan IIRC. It's quick to test though

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in NodeJS using a `express.static`:

```
const FS = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const bp = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

function fileTest(req, res, next){
  if (/\.|\/|\\/.test(req.params.file))
    return res.sendStatus(400)
  return next();
}

app.get(
  '/static/:file',
  fileTest,
  function(req, res, next){
    req.url = req.url.replace('/static','')
    next()
  },
  express.static(
    './static',
    {
      fallthrough: false
    }
  )
)

app.post(
  '/static/:file',
  fileTest,
  bp.text(),
  function (req, res) {
    FS.writeFile(
      './static/'+req.params.file,
      req.body,
      function (err) {
        if(err)
          return res.sendStatus(500)
        return res.sendStatus(200)
      }
    )
  }
)

app.listen(
  1337
)
```

This is a simple example showing a server that will:

[POST]

- Take a text body and load it into memory( pitfall: large bodies in memory )
- Based on the URL, save it as a file in the static folder

[GET]

- Search for a file
- If found return file

The good news is that you can make the file and then request the file without restarting the server. Bad news is that this is a VERY SLOW server( comparatively to other options ).

As with all examples no good practices were followed, so be sure to adapt it to your needs.

## Things to think about as you adopt it:

- How do I allow people to save files to other folders?
- How do I disallow people from saving files to other folders I don't want them to?
- PROPER AUTHORIZATION

Comment: thanks for the answer. What we did was to copy the requested to file to a temp folder inside the public folder and serve it. it worked. Have to test and figure a way to purge the temp files. Let me try your example.